# Counting how many MySQL fields in a row are filled in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to write a method that would allow me to calculate how many fields in a row have been filled by a user.
For example:

```
 User    Name    Age    Country    Gender    Height
    1       Mike    34     USA        Male      6
    2       Bill    23     CA                   5
    3       Jane    31     USA
```

In the above example, I would like to query the database and return a value that would reflect the degree of completion of the user's record. Such as:

```
User 1 = 100% complete
User 2 = 80% complete
User 3 = 60% complete
```

I am using Codeigniter 3. Can you guys help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a method pass a parameter in method

```
  function profileCompleted($user){
         $percentage = 0;
         $sql ="SELECT * FROM user  WHERE user=$user"
       $query = $this->db->query($sql);

      if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
          { 
            $notEmpty =   0;
            $totalField =5;
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
              {
               $notEmpty +=  ($row->Name != '') ? 1 : 0;
                //do with all field
              }
          $percentage = $notEmpty/$totalField *100;
          }
        return $percentage.'%';
    }
```

Comment: How do i display that value in my view.

Comment: By passing the parameter in load function call this method in controller it returns the result and just pass in view same like other data u passed

Comment: This method return only percentage if u want to return more data then add variable in foreach and if there is where condition then it display only single user

Comment: I think i have confused you, anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You may try like this way ::

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `MyTable`');
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
$empty_count = 0;
$count = count($row);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    if($row[$i] === '' || $row[$i] === 'NULL')
        $empty_count++;
echo 'User '.$row[0].' = '.((int)(100*(1-$empty_count/($count-1)))).'% complete';
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be done by SQL query also:

```
SELECT id,
(
    CASE name WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    +
    CASE WHEN age IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    +
    CASE country WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    +
    CASE gender WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    +
    CASE WHEN height IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
) * 100 / number_of_fields AS complete
from your_table;
```